# Handlebars output all fields in iteration with exclusions

Tags: handlebars.js

If I have the following json:

```
{
    "a": 1,
    "b": 2,
    "c": 3,
    "d": 4,
    "e": 5,
}
```

I would like to output all of the json fields into HTML:

```
<div>
{{#each this}}
    <p>{{@key}} - {{this}}</p>
{{/each}}
</div>
```

This would output the following:

```
<div>
    <p>a - 1</p>
    <p>b - 2</p>
    <p>c - 3</p>
    <p>d - 4</p>
    <p>e - 5</p>
</div>
```

However, how could I use this loop to exclude the field `c` from the iteration:

```
<div>
{{#each this}}
    {{#if key does not equal 'c'}}
        <p>{{@key}} - {{this}}</p>
    {{#if key does not equal 'c'}}
{{/each}}
</div>
```

Such that the output is:

```
<div>
    <p>a - 1</p>
    <p>b - 2</p>
    <p>d - 4</p>
    <p>e - 5</p>
</div>
```

How can this be achieved using Handlebars.js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set up a custom helper to return true when a condition is false

```js
var data = {
  "a": 1,
  "b": 2,
  "c": 3,
  "d": 4,
  "e": 5,
};

var source = $("#entry-template").html();


Handlebars.registerHelper("notEqual", function(target, condition, options) {

  if (target !== condition) {
    return options.fn(this);
  } else {
    return options.inverse(this);
  }

});
var tempalte = Handlebars.compile(source);

$("body").append(tempalte(data));
```

```html
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/1.3.0/handlebars.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script id="entry-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
  <div>
    {{#each this}} 
      {{#notEqual @key 'c'}}
        <p>{{@key}} - {{this}}</p>
      {{/notEqual}} 
    {{/each}}
  </div>
</script>
```